# Hiding all kind of update notifications for users using GPO

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

Has someone a GPO in place, or knows how to create one, that hides all kind of update notifications for normal windows accounts that log on over RDP?

Especially the notifications about pending restart after installation and the notification about new updates being available are going on my nerves.

I have found a lot of different possible settings to accomplish this, but I don't really have the time and a system to try out, so I thought I'd ask the experienced people :)

Thanks!

Comment: We're not here to do your job for you. "I haven't had enough time" is a bit insulting, IMO. It's like saying "Someone do this for me, my time is more important than yours"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720539%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) link. In general, you should have all the settings are clearly explained at the description of the WSUS config in the GPO. Just disable whatever notification needed for the required group of users.